# How to choose a language and a quality for HLS input in FFmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming

I need to retranslate HLS to RTMP with FFmpeg. I can do it like this:

```bash
ffmpeg -i 'http://example.com/master.m3u8' -c:v copy -c:a aac -f flv rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/SOME_KEY
```

But master.m3u8 contains a lot of languages and qualities. How to choose these parameters in command line?

Answer (score 1):

In my case I have a few programs in input HLS. Each quality have itself program:

```
    Program 0 
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 2081200
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Main) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(tv, bt470bg), 1024x576 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 2081200
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC) ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 2081200
  Program 1 
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 1399200
    Stream #0:2: Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(tv, bt470bg), 1024x576 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 1399200
    Stream #0:3: Audio: aac (LC) ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 1399200
  Program 2 
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 752400
    Stream #0:4: Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(tv, bt470bg), 1024x576 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 752400
    Stream #0:5: Audio: aac (LC) ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 752400
```

Try to define program by `map` flag:

```
ffmpeg -i 'http://example.com/master.m3u8' -map p:2 -c:v copy -c:a aac -f flv rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/SOME_KEY
```